# Viewing info pages in a browser

Tags: info

Is there any way I can use a browser to view `info` pages? I know that it can be done with man pages based on the man page for `man`, but I couldn't find any such option for info.

Answer (score 8):

Info files are created from `.texinfo` source, which is a special kind of markup language. The program used to convert .texinfo files to .info files is [*GNU TexInfo*](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/). This software can also produce HTML output:

> Texinfo uses a single source file to produce output in a number of
>   formats, both online and printed (dvi, html, info, pdf, xml, etc.).
>   This means that instead of writing different documents for online
>   information and another for a printed manual, you need write only one
>   document.

For instance, you can use the [coreutils.texi](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/doc/coreutils.texi) file with [`texi2any`](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#Generic-Translator-texi2any):

```
texi2any --html --no-split --no-headers --force -o core.htm coreutils.texi
```

to produce a single *html* file with the entire content from the *coreutils* info pages.

Note the [`info`](http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/info-stnd.html#Top) utility, which is also part of the *texinfo* suite, allows for some exporting of the content, but not directly to html; for instance:

```
info --subnodes -o ls.txt ls
```

to output the `ls` command `info` content to a text file.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what you did there @illuminÉ. When I tried to execute that command, my terminal gave me the message ``could not open coreutils.texi: No such file or directory``.

Comment: Thanks for adding the instructions. Can you do something like ``info --subnodes -o ls.texi ls`` to get output in Texinfo?

Comment: Note, also, that `info --subnodes -o foo.txt foo.info` will convert the subject `.info` file to a text file. Very useful.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, KDE's Konqueror and Rekonq browsers can display info pages directly, by exposing them through the `info:` protocol.

Simply launch Konqueror or Rekonq, and type e.g. "info:ls" in the address bar to access the info page for `ls`.

`man` pages are supported in the same way, via the `man:` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

The current releases’ `info` pages are available on [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/manual/). They come in different formats including HTML and nice `tex`y PDF, e. g. for the coreutils:

- [gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual) – overview
- [gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html) – one big HTML
- [gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html) – one HTML page per node
- [gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.pdf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.pdf) – shiny PDF

A simple function to easily open e. g. the big HTML version of given packages could be:

```bsh
infohtml(){
  for i; do
    vivaldi-stable "https://www.gnu.org/software/$i/manual/$i.html"
  done
}
```

With this, a command line `infohtml bash screen` opens the online info pages of these two using `vivaldi-stable` – replace the browser command if necessary.

Comment: I'm looking for the info page for `top` online.   I couldn't find it in any of those links.

Comment: @Katerl3s That’s because `top` is not a GNU package, refer to the manpage instead, e.g. for [Ubuntu Focal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/top.1.html).